# Android Makes Floating Action Menu in FIXED position

Tags: android, listview, scroll, fixed, floating-action-button

Hi I'm new in Android dev.

I set the below code:

```
listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

to hide the top toolbar when I scroll the listView. However, all child views are moved, including the Floating Action Menu.

I want the Floating Action Menu to stay idle, fixed at the position, and not influenced by the NestedScrollingEnabled behavior. Apparently it affects the parent view.

[image]

Any solution to this? Thank you.

My xml roughly looks like this (Just ignore the attached images which is abit different from the xml codes, because it is too long, but the general idea is there):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_price_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e3e3e3">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_below="@+id/buttons_selection_container">

           <FrameLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorProgressBarPrimary"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"/>

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_no_data"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No Price Data"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

                <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView_prices"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
                </ListView>
           </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/price_fragment_float_Menu_button"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="376dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/color_float_blue_dark"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_switch_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/color_float_blue_lite"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/button_different_currencies"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_title="Switch Price"/>
    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Create floating button in another view and include that your layout

Comment: Use a [Google FAB button](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons) instead of custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the FAB button when the listview is scrolled using a custom layout behavior atrribute

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {


private static final String TAG = "ScrollingFABBehavior";

public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
    // Log.e(TAG, "ScrollAwareFABBehavior");
}


public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    if (dependency instanceof RecyclerView)
        return true;

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                           FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed,
                           int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
            dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    //Log.e(TAG, "onNestedScroll called");
    if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
     //   Log.e(TAG, "child.hide()");
        child.hide();
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
      //  Log.e(TAG, "child.show()");
        child.show();
    }
}}
```

layout xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/imageViewYes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_yes"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="com.your.package.ScrollingFABBehavior" />
```

Comment: Not good. I want user to always see the floating button. It will only fade to 0.4f alpha when the list view reaches the last row of result. My solution now is none so far. Leave it to up and down depends on the scrolling behaviour. Will try to put the floating button inside the listview layout.